# Easing towards stepped value

Tags: c++, lua, easing

I'm currently developing this rhythm game in lua (on top of a c++ engine) and I'm having trouble keeping a steady playhead position for the song currently playing.

The playhead position that the engine gives me updates in steps, so I get a fresh one every 2, 3 or 4 frames. But I need to have a steady one for sprites moving smoothly with the rhythm and stuff.

So I just keep track of my own playhead variable, which I initialize in 0 and then constantly add delta time to it. This variable eventually gets out of sync with the actual playhead, so every time I get a fresh playhead (or a "new step"), I correct my variable using the average between these two.

This however results in choppy movement.

What would be the best way to ease my playhead variable into the stepped one?

This is the code I excecute every frame:

-- add delta to my own playhead variable

```
playhead = playhead + delta_time
```

-- if there's a new stepped_playhead value, correct my playhead

```
if stepped_playhead ~= last_stepped_playhead then
    playhead = (playhead + stepped_playhead) / 2
    last_stepped_playhead = stepped_playhead
end
```

Comment: Maybe better for [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: you should provide some code of yours.

Comment: @GameDev you are right, thanks.

Comment: You cannot achieve this on non real-time system. Instead you have to track the time difference between updates (delta_time will be different for every update) and adjust the animation accordingly.

Comment: @Archie "Time difference between updates" <-- Do you mean between the stepped values? If that's what you meant, you're right, that time varies from 2 to 4 or 5 frames. The thing is that I don't know how to adjust my playhead value to smoothly go near the stepped one. Do you have any suggestions?